# C3P0 APPARENT DEADLOCK in Apache Tomcat application

Tags: java, postgresql, c3p0

I am seeing a C3P0 log dead lock issue in an Apache Tomcat application.

Not long after this I begin to see failures in Tomcat due to resource limits.

This then causes the number of httpd daughter processes to increase until the maxRequestWorkers limit is hit and the server then deadlocks.

From my initial research it looks like the C3P0 issue could be a failure of hibernate to communicate with postgres.

A confirmation of whether that is the root issue would be appreciated as well as any insight into what might be going on here.

This is this initial log that C3P0 issues:

```
[WARN] [Wed Feb 08 05:52:41.589 2023] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-AdminTaskTimer|ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@578de344 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
[WARN] [Wed Feb 08 05:52:42.270 2023] [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-AdminTaskTimer|ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@578de344 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 10
    Active Threads: 10
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@148953c6
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@33ec4718
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#5
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7a772c6f
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#7
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5e288adc
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@e1f5bc
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#4
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@51e4b63f
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#8
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1233fc38
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#3
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@857fac8
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#6
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@794b26b
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@73b5a9e8
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2t53wqaub1kdwl1wutziz|421f447f]-HelperThread-#9
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@7e6a499a
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@49dc7d25
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@6b79999f
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@355d97f1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@19572e59
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@33c84d03
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@145a8f84
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@4d6160e1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6de4aaf2
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@1cb54218
Pool thread stack traces:
...
```

Not long after this is the resource issues that tomcat starts to log:

```
08-Feb-2023 05:52:49.672 SEVERE [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-123] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Failed to complete processing of a request
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
```

ps shows that soon after Tomcat begins to error a large number of httpd processes begins to spawn.  This continues for several hours until the  limit of 500 is hit.

```
[vcr@qa-9440 ~]$ ps auxwww |grep httpd
root     4154    0.0  0.0    23504    10668  -  Ss   Mon17       0:33.03 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     45854    0.0  0.0    23504    11452  -  I    05:53       0:01.41 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     46742    0.0  0.0    23504    11448  -  I    05:54       0:00.84 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     46986    0.0  0.0    23504    11412  -  I    05:55       0:00.67 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47031    0.0  0.0    23504    11436  -  I    05:55       0:00.54 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47034    0.0  0.0    23504    11444  -  I    05:55       0:00.60 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47223    0.0  0.0    26064    11600  -  I    05:55       0:00.43 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47390    0.0  0.0    23504    11412  -  I    05:56       0:00.40 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47411    0.0  0.0    23504    11428  -  I    05:56       0:00.32 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47520    0.0  0.0    23504    11384  -  I    05:56       0:00.30 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47617    0.0  0.0    23504    11408  -  I    05:56       0:00.28 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47619    0.0  0.0    23504    11336  -  I    05:56       0:00.22 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47653    0.0  0.0    23504    11356  -  I    05:56       0:00.23 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47716    0.0  0.0    23504    11340  -  I    05:56       0:00.20 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
www     47735    0.0  0.0    23504    11364  -  I    05:56       0:00.18 /usr/local/sbin/httpd -DNOHTTPACCEPT
...
```

C3P0/Hibernate configurations:

```
<!-- Configure the dataSource.-->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${db.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${db.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${db.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${db.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="2000" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="5" />
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Setup Hibernate based on config file 
        classpath:com/niksun/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml.
        
        PostgreSQLDialect
    -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect 
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <!--prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop-->
                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Why do you have your hibernate maxPoolSize 5 times over the limit defined for the c3p0 config?

Comment: @JorgeCampos not sure, I did not configure this, just trying to debug this issue.

Comment: I would start by matching those parameters or even removing it from the hibernate config as the datasource using c3p0 as pool is responsible to manage that and not hibernate. The worst it can happen is the server to fail faster as "allegedly" there will be less connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task that's hanging and saturating your thread pool is `ScatteredAcquireTask`, which is c3p0 trying to get new Connections from the backend DB. Those attempts are *hanging*, meaning they are neither succeeding nor failing with an `Exception`. They are just indefinitely holding up the `Thread` that tries to run them. This hang is what you need to debug. This sort of hang can come from, e.g. incorrect authentication configuration on AWS, but also from lots of other mysteries. If you can try a test program that simply tries to acquire a `Connection` with the same dbUrl/user/password when these events happen, that might give some insight.

Failure is normal. `c3p0` is very resilient to the fact that `Connection` acquisition sometimes fails, networks and databases are imperfect. But it is not resilient to neither failing nor succeeding. It expects acquisition attempts to either succeed, or fail within a pretty generous time window. Indefinite hangs will eat up its threads.

Comment: To anyone that reads this it looks like the root cause was the server was coming under heavy load intermittently.  During these periods communication with the postgress would hang ( along with many other processes).